# Ember.js textarea "on" action

Tags: ember.js

`{{textarea value=order.note action="autoSave" on="focus-out"}}`

I have a very strange problem. When I want to use on="" action event with a textarea I get following error:

`initember.debug.js:43662TypeError: this.on is not a function. (In 'this.on("paste", this, this._elementValueDidChange)', 'this.on' is "focus-out")`

Answer (score 0):

You want this:

```
{{textarea value=order.note focus-out="autoSave"}}
```